# Adding JScrollPane on a JList without using JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jlist

I need help on my program. I need to have a JScrollPane on a JList without putting JList on a JPanel.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class refurbished extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    ArrayList<String> names;
    JButton add;
    JTextField inputName;
    JScrollPane scrollName;
    JList nameList;

public refurbished() {
    setSize(700,500);
    setLayout(null);

    names = new ArrayList<String>();

    add = new JButton("Add");
    add.setBounds(25,200,90,30);
    add.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    add.addActionListener(this);

    inputName = new JTextField();
    inputName.setBounds(150,350,150,30);

    nameList = new JList(names.toArray());

    scrollName = new JScrollPane(nameList);
    scrollName.setBounds(150,75,150,200);

    getContentPane().add(add);
    getContentPane().add(inputName);
    getContentPane().add(scrollName);

    setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent buttonclick) {
    if (buttonclick.getSource() == add) {
        names.add(inputName.getText().toLowerCase());
        nameList = new JList(names.toArray());
        scrollName = new JScrollPane(nameList);
        scrollName.setBounds(150,75,150,200);
}
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    refurbished r = new refurbished();
}
```

}

Can you help me? I really need your help because this is the only missing feature in my code.

Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: JScrollPane on a JList.

Comment: you need scroll bars in list when the content exceeds the height of the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yout haven't added the lists to the scroll panes. You've only added the lists to the contentpane.

```
scrollName = new JScrollPane();
scrollNumber = new JScrollPane();

getContentPane().add(nameList);      <-- Get rid of this
getContentPane().add(numberList);    <-- Get rid of this
```

You need this instead

```
scrollName = new JScrollPane(nameList);
scrollNumber = new JScrollPane(numberList);

getContentPane().add(scrollName);      
getContentPane().add(scrollNumber);
```

Also as @Alex2410 noted in his comment below, ***"Also you need to use LayoutManager, or set Bounds to JScrollPane rather then to JList"***

**Update:** to original poster update

You need to both `revalidate()` *and* `repaint()` after adding or removing components. Add `revalidate()` before where you have `repaint()`. You only need to `revalidate()` `repaint()` once in the method

---

**Edit:**  If you want to update the list, use a ListModel. You don't need to replace the entire list with a new list

See this code. What I've done is used a `DefaultListModel` and set that model to the `Jlist`. Then you can add element to the list dynamically. I fixed your code and it works. I commented on the adds and what I removed

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class refurbished extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    ArrayList<String> names;
    JButton add;
    JTextField inputName;
    JScrollPane scrollName;
    JList nameList;
    DefaultListModel model;          <-- declare DefaultListModel

    public refurbished() {
        setSize(700, 500);
        setLayout(null);

        names = new ArrayList<String>();

        add = new JButton("Add");
        add.setBounds(25, 200, 90, 30);
        add.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add.addActionListener(this);

        inputName = new JTextField();
        inputName.setBounds(150, 350, 150, 30);

        model = new DefaultListModel();                <-- Initialize model
        nameList = new JList(model);                   <-- set model to list

        scrollName = new JScrollPane(nameList);
        scrollName.setBounds(150, 75, 150, 200);

        getContentPane().add(add);
        getContentPane().add(inputName);
        getContentPane().add(scrollName);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonclick) {
        if (buttonclick.getSource() == add) {
            //names.add(inputName.getText().toLowerCase());   
            //nameList = new JList(names.toArray());        <-- don't need all this
            //scrollName = new JScrollPane(nameList);
            //scrollName.setBounds(150, 75, 150, 200);
            String name = inputName.getText();           <-- get input
            names.add(name);                             
            model.addElement(name);                      <-- add name to model      
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        refurbished r = new refurbished();
    }
}
```

Take a look at [**`Using Models`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/model.html). You should take time to learn the MVC (Model, View, Controller) paradigm.

Comment: Also you need to use `LayoutManager`, or set Bounds to `JScrollPane` rather then to `JList`.

Comment: Nah, save every bodies stress levels and use a layout manager

Comment: i'll give a try on this one.

Comment: You need to both `revalidate()` and `repaint()`. Adding or removing components. Add `revalidate()` before where you have repaint()

Comment: You only need to revalidate() repaint() once in the method

Comment: Without Layout managers, you will have a hard time adding and removing components. See this [Laying out components with Layout Managers] tutorial.

Comment: can you provide the link?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that, [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Maybe because you;re doing that EXACT same thing again as your original code.. not adding the list the the scroll pane

Comment: posted another update. sorry i didn't update my code immediately but i changed it right after you've commented.

Comment: Do this, put together the SMALLEST piece of code possible that compiles and runs (this is known as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Make sure to only include the necessary components that cause this problem. So basically your duplicating the exact problem into a smaller program that we can test out. It's hard to tell your problem without being to run a program.

Comment: And why are you adding the lists to the to the GUI when a button is pressed? Why not just have the lists already in the frame when the program opens?

Comment: i teared down my code. :)
the lists is already in the frame when the program runs.

Comment: sorry i'm very noob at programming.

Comment: Thanks for the SSCCE. What exactly do you want to accomplish? You want what you type to show up in the list?

Comment: have the scrollpane implemented on the JList and show the contacts i've added to the list. :)

Comment: So you want to type in a name into the text field, then that name show up in the list?

Comment: yes. and i can now also implement the code to the remove part if the code's finish. :)

Comment: You don't really need the ArrayList at all. Unless you need to use it elsewhere in your program.

Comment: I have another question. I have a button that sorts out the list alphabetically. Will i just put repaint() and revalidate() to refresh the list?

Comment: No, you need to clear the model `model.clear()`, then loop adding again all the sorted elements. `for (String name : names) { model.addElement(name); }`.

Comment: i also have another question. my goal now is to remove the name and the number. example if you input shaun on the text field, shaun will be removed and the number will also be removed. tried to get back to my old code but it isn't working.